# How to show the logo as soon as possible when launch the app in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

There alway a black screen when the app launch, for about 1 second.
But for some other apps, there show the logo or something else as soon as possible. 
How they made it??
Could any one provided some code?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: if you do any heavy tasks at the starter activity, then using AsyncTask may solve the issue.

Comment: I think you are talking about **splash screen**. If so, this is an example:  http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/

Comment: Great, thanks, splash screen is exactly what I want.